# get row with className

Tags: jquery

How can you get the first row in a table with a specific className?

```
var rows = $('tr', tbl);
```

Comment: `$('tr.className:first', tbl)` jQuery has good documentation: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ Read it, much faster than asking questions here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var rows = $('tr.classname:first', tbl);
```

or

```
var rows = $('tr.classname', tbl).first();
```

Docs here: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 2):

```
var firstRow = $('tr.classname:first', tbl)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) selector along with the [class](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) selector,

Try this:

```
var rows = $('tr.someclass:first', tbl);
```

Answer (score 0):

`var row = $("tr.className:first", tbl);` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If you keep the proprietary `:first` selector out of it, you'll have a valid `querySelectorAll` selector.

```
var rows = tbl.find('tr.someClass').slice( 0, 1 );
```

or

```
var rows = tbl.find('tr.someClass').eq( 0 );
```

Also, using the context parameter `$( selector, context )` is just a slower way of using the [`find()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/find/) method.

Answer (score 0):

You can even use **eq** method of jquery if you want to loop through a list of elements.

```
var rows = $('tr.classname');
rows.eq(0);//first row
rows.eq(1);//second row
```