# get row by index

Tags: jquery

how can you get a row by the index?

```
var rows = $('tr', tbl);
rows.index(0).addClass('my_class');
```

Comment: Again, jQuery has good documentation: http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/. You want `eq`.

Comment: eq() isn't really named like something to do with this..

Comment: This was answered in [your last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6428375/get-row-with-classname).

Comment: @clarkk: Why not? It says *"Reduce the set of matched elements to the one at the specified index."* You have a set of rows (`rows`), you want the one with a certain index (`0`). Seems to fit very well.

Comment: the answer was added later on

Comment: I'd agree with @Felix. Also, if you just type `index` into the "Search jQuery" field, you'll get your answer.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use `.eq()`.

```
var rows = $('tr', tbl);
rows.eq(0).addClass('my_class');
```

...or for your simple case, `.first()`:

```
rows.first().addClass('my_class');
```

Comment: Could you elaborate what `tbl` is or how to get it in jQuery?

Answer (score 9):

Using either the [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) function:

```
rows.eq(0).addClass('my_class');
```

Or the [`:eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) selector:

```
$('tr:eq(0)', tbl).addClass('my_class');
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var row=$('tr:eq(5)', tbl);  // returns the 5th row
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use the native [`rows`*<sup>[docs]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/table.rows) property on the `HTMLTableElement`.

```
$(tbl[0].rows[0]).addClass('my_class');
```

---

As noted by [@Felix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/218196/felix-kling), I've assumed that `tbl` is a jQuery object. If not, do this:

```
$(tbl.rows[0]).addClass('my_class');
```

Comment: +1 because this is something less trivial to find (imo). But maybe `tbl` is not a jQuery object...

Comment: @Felix: True. I'm assuming that about `tbl`. I'll update. EDIT: And thanks for the docs link. :o)

Answer (score 3):

you can do

```
$('tr:eq(0)', tbl).addClass('my_class');
```

more on this http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/

Answer (score 3):

You can use nth-child in your selector:

```
$('tr td:nth-child(3)').addClass('my_class');
```

Will get the third td.

Answer (score 2):

Use [eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)

```
$('tr', tbl).eq(0).addClass('my_class');
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first element (index 0) the answer provided to your earlier question should be fine.

For any nth element use [eq](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) selector

e.g:

```
var rows = $('tr:eq(8)', tbl);
```

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/get/ says:

> Retrieve the DOM elements matched by the jQuery object.
>   .get( [index] )
>    index A zero-based integer indicating which element to retrieve.

Note that you'll get the DOM object, not a jQuery one:

```
var rows = $('tr', tbl);
$(rows.get(0)).addClass('my_class');
```