# What is the second argument in this jquery select statement?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-context

I have seen it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6428658/get-row-by-index). What is meant by `tbl` in the following statement? What does it imply?

```
var rows = $('tr', tbl);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `tbl` in the above is another dom element. This is passed in as the (optional parameter) `context`:

```
jQuery( selector [, context ] )
```

...for the `selector`, in this case `'tr'`.

### [source](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery1)

---

So essentially this:

```
$('tr', tbl);
```

says *return me everything that matches the selector `'tr'` in the element(s) `tbl`*.

---

### Example

So given

```
<table>
  <tr>first</tr>
<table>
<table id="test">
   <tr>second</tr>
</table>
```

This returns varying results:

```
//context is global
$('tr') => first & second

//restrict the context to just the second table 
//by finding it and passing it into the selector
var tbl = $('#test');
$('tr', tbl) => just second
```

Comment: why selector is written as `selector [`   and context as `context ]` in `jQuery( selector [, context ] ` ? I am sure there must be some thought behind it?

Comment: context is optional so it's `[,context]` (i.e. context is an optional parameter) . selector is not optional so it's not in square braces. @user3198603

Answer (score 2):

This pattern is using jQuery context. Your query is used to find the rows within the table.

```
var tbl = $("table#tableId"); // this line provides the context
var rows = $("tr", tbl); // finding all rows within the context
```

This is equivalent to writing

```
var rows = tbl.find("tr")
```

There is good explanation on using jQuery context in this [SO Question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16422478/what-is-context-in-jquery-selector)