# Whats the meaning of $('element',this.el)[0]?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, marionette

Now I learning Backbone and Marionette, I read some tutorial and I found a code whom I haven't understand. Here's the code:

```
$('element',this.el)[0]
```

I know jQuery little bit. I know `this` keyword, i know the `$('element')` keyword, but not understand that code, please everybody tell me about that.

Comment: It finds the `element` within `this.el` and returns the DOMElement from the resulting jQuery object.

Comment: can you provide full code

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-selector-context

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This `$('element',this.el)` says select all `<element>` contained within `this.el`. `this.el` must be another "object" but what it is depends on what is building this higher up. I cover this in more detail in [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37257133/542251).

---

The `[0]` simply unwraps the jquery object returning a vanilla DOM object. So:

```
$('element',this.el).first(); //works
$('element',this.el)[0].first(); //will error
```

The second errors becuase it is no longer a jquery object so it is not wrapped in the jquery functions.

Comment: So can I say that code is "select first element which has name `element` in `this.el` element" ?

Comment: almost: "select first element which **of the type** element in this.el **and then unwrap the jquery object from around it**"

Comment: I do not understand a bit of what you are talking about, can you add an simple diagram image or something like that so I can fast understand what are you saying?

Comment: I owuld suggest you have a look though the [jquery learning docs](http://learn.jquery.com/). I don't think I can simplify it anymore than I can. This is very basic jquery

Answer (score 2):

- In Backbone context, your code is probably found inside [a view](http://backbonejs.org/#View) and `this.el` refers to the [view's element](http://backbonejs.org/#View-el)
- `$('element',this.el)` find the `element` nodes inside the scope defined by `this.el`
- `$('element',this.el)[0]` refers to the first `element` node found

Note that in a Backbone view, you can simplify to

```
this.$('element')[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the [jquery selector context](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-selector-context) syntax:

`'element'` is to a selector and `this.el` is a context and using bracket notation to get the first element `[0]` which also converts jquery element to javascript object.

Alternatively you can use like this instead of jquery selector context syntax:

```
$(this.el).find('element')[0] // hope you understand this syntax
```