# InTableControl buttons of datatable editor not working when in child tr (responsive mode)

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, jquery-datatables-editor

I'm using datatable editor with inTableControl buttons. The inTableControl buttons work fine when the table is in normal status, but in combination with responsive and if the inTableControl buttons are in the child tr (when collapsed in the dropdown), the sample js is not working. There are no records to edit in the modal. Does anyone know how to adjust the js for the inTableControl buttons for them also to work when in the child tr? I tried a couple of things like .parent().prev('parent') , .closest('tr.child').prev('tr.parent'), .closest('tr').prev('tr') , .parent().prev('tr') .... but none of them work. And do I need an if for both status? How would that look like?

This works fine ...

```
var edit_inTable_editor_bafin = $('#bafin').on('click', 'a.editor_cog', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    editor_bafin.edit( $(this).closest('tr'), {
        title: 'Edit record',
        buttons: 'Update'
    } );

} );

<tr id="row_2812" class="odd selected parent" role="row">
 <td>Test</td>
 <td class=" datatable-link" style="">
  <a class="editor_cog" title="Edit Entity" role="button" href="">
 </td>
</tr>
```

... but when the inTableControl buttons are in child tr (dropdown of responsive):

```
<tr id="row_2812" class="odd selected parent" role="row">
<tr class="child">
 <td class="child" colspan="15">
  <ul data-dtr-index="0">
   <li data-dtr-index="11">...</li>
   <li data-dtr-index="12">...</li>
   <li data-dtr-index="13">...</li>
    <span class="dtr-title"></span>
    <span class="dtr-data">
     <a class="editor_cog" title="Edit Entity" role="button" href="">Edit</a>
    </span>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </td>
</tr>
```

...

Comment: Is it because `closest('tr')` returns `<tr class="child">` rather than `<tr id="row_2812" class="odd selected parent" role="row">`?  You could easily check that in Firebug.

Comment: Yes that's correct. But all my attempts (see above) to get the id of the parent tr failed.

Comment: If the `tr` always has `class="odd selected parent"`, then you can use that to ensure you're getting the correct `tr`. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6428375/get-row-with-classname)

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem. But I solved it this way

```
 $('#tb_sos tbody').on( 'click', 'input.aja', function () {

        var tr=$(this).parents('tr');
        if ($(tr).hasClass("child")){
          var api = tablaSOS.tabla.row( $(this).parents('tr').prev('tr') ).data();
        }else{
          var api = tablaSOS.tabla.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data();
        }
        console.log(api);

  } );
```

Comment: Can you explain your solution instead of just dumping code, so that others can learn from it?

Comment: When row is in responsive, and the button is inside the hidden data, the buttons are children of a td not of tr